# Deleted an Oracle table, now cannot create a table with the same name

Tags: sql, oracle

I am on Oracle 12c, and deleted a base table `WIP_DISCRETE_JOBS`. We had created a backup table like:

```
CREATE TABLE WDJ_BKP AS (SELECT * FROM WIP_DISCRETE_JOBS) 

DROP TABLE WIP_DISCRETE_JOBS;
COMMIT;
```

Now when I try to restore from backup table it gives error.

```
CREATE TABLE WIP_DISCRETE_JOBS AS (SELECT * FROM WDJ_BKP) 
ORA-00955 name is already used by existing object.
```

But if we query `ALL_OBJECTS` with `WIP_DISCRETE_JOBS` no rows are returned. 
What is the problem?

Comment: There is a similar question on the DBA stack exchange : https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/12376/how-do-i-find-an-object-that-doesnt-seem-to-exist-in-the-objects-table

Comment: Can you create the table without the select? Something like `create table WIP_DISCRETE_JOBS (x number(6));`, or this sentence also fails?

Comment: Can you show us the output of `SELECT * FROM ALL_OBJECTS WHERE UPPER(object_name) IN ('WDJ_BKP','WIP_DISCRETE_JOBS');` after the `DROP`?

Comment: @TheImpaler - that give same error.

Comment: @wolφi - this command shows only WDJ_BKP

Comment: Could you also query `DBA_OBJECTS` ?

Comment: Hmm, very strange (and not reproducable, it works for me, see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/71642/2/1).

Can you ask somebody with admin rights to run the query `SELECT * FROM DBA_OBJECTS WHERE UPPER(object_name) IN ('WDJ_BKP','WIP_DISCRETE_JOBS'); `

Comment: I used the query for Oracle raw data dictionary using sys.obj$ o, sys.user$ and i can see many objects with the WIP_DISCRETE_JOBS name and TYPE = unknown. Also one synonym with the same name but i cant find it in ALL_OBJECTS or DBA_OBJECTS. Is this the reason, if yes how to resolve

Comment: @wolφi DBA_OBJECTS also dont have it. I have queried from SYSTEM user.

Comment: There was a bug in 11.2, try emptying the recyclebin as SYSTEM user `PURGE dba_recyclebin`, flush the pool `alter system flush shared_pool` and rerun your sys.obj$ query...

Comment: Was unable to do PURGE dba_recyclebin as SYSTEM - no privilege. Checking with DBA

Answer (score 1):

We finally resolved this issue. Problem: Oracle 11gR2 onwards, database has editions, which is type of versions. You have a current edition. You need to query ALL_OBJECTS or DBA_OBJECTS after setting the edition

`ALTER SESSION SET EDITION=<EDITION NAME>`

to see objects in other editions.

All sessions can be queried from DBA_EDITIONS

There were some editions having a synonym for this table with the same name. After we deleted the synonyms by setting to each edition, we were able to create the table.

Comment: Thanks for finding a solution to this rather tricky problem. I'd recommend that you accept the answer for clarity (any you'll get points :-)

Answer (score -1):

DROP TABLE WIP_DISCRETE_JOBS purge;

Comment: That won't help, purge empties the recycle bin. The table name in the bin is different to the original name.